# Spring boot - Controller catching all URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am building a Spring boot web app and am using annotations for controller/url mapping.

I have several controllers annotated with `@RequestMapping` with the url value set (both empty strings and specific URLs) which are working fine e.g.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/accounts")
class SignInController {

    @Autowired PartyService partyService

    @RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String signinPage( Model model) {
```

Navigating to /accounts renders the sign-in page correctly.

However, if I add a controller with no `RequestMapping` values e.g.

```
@Controller
class CustomController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String transform( Model model ) {
```

Then any URL I enter that doesn't match any other specific controller is getting handled by this controller (so pages I would expect to 404 all just renderthis page).  Is this expected behaviour? I was not expecting this, and as the RequestMapping value defaults to empty and is an antMatcher I wouldn't have thought it would handle all other URLs.

The reason I have this controller with out `RequestMapping` defined is because I want to also have a `SimpleUrlMappingHandler` defined with some explicit URLs going to that controller, and if I don't include the `@Controller` & `@RequestMapping` annotations to that controller then I get an error about not being able to find the handler method (maybe the problem is that I have mis-understood the implementation details of that).

Should my custom controller be handling all URLs?  If so, is there something I can do so it doesnt and only gets called for the explicit `SimpleUrlMappingHandler` I have defined?

Comment: If you want a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` then don't use `@Controller` as that is intended for something else. Implement the `Controller` interface for these controllers instead.

Comment: Ok, will try that - I was under the impression that @Controller just annotated the class as a "Controller" type component for classpath scanning (assume without that I will need to define the controller explicitly in the config) - Is that controller intercepting all other URLs expected behaviour?

Comment: That is true, however the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` detects all `@Controller`s and tries to find all `@RequestMapping` annotated methods on those.

Comment: Ok, thanks that has solved it - if you want to add that as an answer I will accept that.  An aside, I have noticed that my interceptor now doesn't run on requests going to that controller (did before when it was an annotated controller) - I will dig some more into that..

Comment: Ok, see I need to add it explicitly to my SimpleUrlMappingHandler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - I just removed the `@Controller` annotation from the class, and then explicitly defined the controller as a `@Bean` in my config class and explicitly assigned that to the mapping in the `SimpleUrlMappingHandler` configuration