# Any way to use @RequestMapping and @PathVariable in Spring (Boot) to capture a variable path?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to catch any URL, such as:

```
mydomain.com/first/second/third  
mydomain.com/first/second/third/fourth  
mydomain.com/first/
```

and be able to catch it in a single method in my controller and build a string with the path, like:

```
for (String pathVar : pathVariableArray){  
  stringToBuild += pathVar + '.'
}
```

and get the following results:

```
stringToBuild = "first.second.third."  
stringToBuild = "first.second.third.fourth."  
stringToBuild = "first."
```

Is there any way? I don’t want to have to code various methods for a different length of the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public void method(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String stringToBuild = request.getServletPath().replace("/", ".") + ".";
```

For alternate mapping methods, see [Spring boot - Controller catching all URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26633601/476716).

You may need to be more sophisticated to avoid an double `.` at the end if the path ends with a `/`.

Comment: Your answer really did help but I have a slight correction to make.  Because you are using wildcards, you have to use getServletPath instead of getPathInfo, otherwise you'll get a null value.